# Want to redirect specific page to another page using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hey can any one tell me how can i redirect my this page http://www.fastvpnservice.com/best-vpn-for-torrenting.html to another page http://www.fastvpnservice.com/5-best-fastest-vpn.html using .htaccess file, I would be very thankful to someone who will provide me a complete code, I just copy and paste it into my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^best-vpn-for-torrenting\.html$ 5-best-fastest-vpn.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule to redirect the specific url to a new location :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /best-vpn-for-torrenting\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.fastvpnservice.com/5-best-fastest-vpn.html [L,R]
```